# Употребление род. падежа после "не"

Tags: грамматика, падежи, управление, дополнение

В каких случаях употребляется род. падеж после не+глагол?
То есть "Я не вижу красную книгу" или "Я не вижу красной книги"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Я не вижу красную книгу" или "Я не вижу красной книги"?

Зависит от контекста. Если речь об известной красной книге, то пишите: "Я не вижу (эту) красную книгу". В противном случае: "Я не вижу (никакой) красной книги".

Answer (score 2):

Найдите в справочниках тему: "Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием".
В вашем примере, если не знать контекста, оба варианта допустимы.

P.S. *Не знать контекст* или *не знать контекста*?! )